# In java what is the regular expression to add mask to string with certian pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get following strings:

```
8374651-37374-19283-284745800
928S-29ED374-872B34-932837
26598TA-297374-CND283-16373
82911-LD391DB-632D-4927831
```

Looks like this by java regex:

```
XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-284745800
XXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXX-932837
XXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-16373
XXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXX-4927831
```

and there is no pattern about the length of string between each hyphen.

It could be easy to replace everything except hyphen with X but really difficult to me to exclude last part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string.replaceAll` function.

```
string.replaceAll("[^-\\n](?=.*?-)", "X");
```

This matches all the characters (*but not of a hyphen*) which was followed by a hyphen. It won't match the last part since it isn't followed by a hyphen.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aX3gV6/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
[^-\n](?=.*-[^-]*$)
```

Try this.Replace by `X`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/18

For java it will be

```
[^-\\n](?=.*-[^-]*$)
```

The lookahead condition will select only those which are to be replaced by `X`.

Answer (score 0):

or this pattern, replace w/ `x`

```
(?!-).(?=.*-)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/231)